# How can I get a SQL String's collation within a CLR function?

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, collation, sqlclr

I'm writing a Levenshtein Distance function in C# to calculate the edit distance between two strings.  The problem is that I'd like to call the method multiple times with different collations but only one collation ever makes it across the SQL to CLR interface - and that is the default collation of the database.

Here is the code for the CLR Function:

```cs
[SqlFunction(IsDeterministic = true, Name = "LevenshteinDistance")]
public static SqlInt64 Distance(SqlString textA, SqlString textB)
{
    // get a collation-aware comparer so string/character comparisons 
    // will match the inputs' specified collation
    var aCompareInfo = textA.CompareInfo;
    var compareOptions = ConvertCompareOptions(textA.SqlCompareOptions);
    var aLength = textA.Value.Length;
    var bLength = textB.Value.Length;

    // degenerate cases
    if (aCompareInfo.Compare(textA.Value, 0, aLength, textB.Value, 0, bLength, compareOptions) == 0) { return 0; }
    if (aLength == 0) { return bLength; }
    if (bLength == 0) { return aLength; }

    // create two work vectors of integer distances
    var previousDistances = new SqlInt64[Maximum(aLength, bLength) + 1];
    var currentDistances = new SqlInt64[Maximum(aLength, bLength) + 1];

    // initialize previousDistances (the previous row of distances)
    // this row is A[0][i]: edit distance for an empty textA
    // the distance is just the number of characters to delete from textB
    for (var i = 0; i < previousDistances.Length; i++)
    {
        previousDistances[i] = i;
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < aLength; i++)
    {
        // calculate currentDistances from the previous row previousDistances

        // first element of currentDistances is A[i+1][0]
        //   edit distance is delete (i+1) chars from textA to match empty textB
        currentDistances[0] = i + 1;

        // use formula to fill in the rest of the row
        for (var j = 0; j < bLength; j++)
        {
            var cost = (aCompareInfo.Compare(textA.Value, i, 1, textB.Value, j, 1, compareOptions) == 0) ? 0 : 1;
            currentDistances[j + 1] = Minimum(currentDistances[j] + 1, previousDistances[j + 1] + 1, previousDistances[j] + cost);
        }

        // copy currentDistances to previousDistances for next iteration
        for (var j = 0; j < previousDistances.Length; j++)
        {
            previousDistances[j] = currentDistances[j];
        }
    }

    return currentDistances[bLength];
}
```

After deploying the CLR assembly to SQL Server (2008 R2) and calling it like this:

```sql
print dbo.LevenshteinDistance('abc' collate Latin1_General_CI_AI, 'ABC' collate Latin1_General_CI_AI)
print dbo.LevenshteinDistance('abc' collate Latin1_General_CS_AS_KS_WS, N'ABC' collate Latin1_General_CS_AS_KS_WS)
```

Both calls return zero (0).  Because I specified a case-sensitive collation for the second call, I expected that second call to return three (3).

Using CLR functions in SQL Server, is it possible to specify collations other than the database default and have them used within a CLR function?  If so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not seeing any alternatives on the Internet or responses to this question, I decided to specify the desired collation attributes as function parameters and select a `CultureInfo` object and `CompareOptions` based upon the inputs or the default collation passed in from the database.

```cs
[SqlFunction(IsDeterministic = true, Name = "LevenshteinDistance")]
public static SqlInt64 Distance(SqlString textA, SqlString textB, int? lcid, bool? caseInsensitive, bool? accentInsensitive, bool? kanaInsensitive, bool? widthInsensitive)
{
    // get a collation-aware comparer so string/character comparisons 
    // will match the inputs' specified collation
    //var aCompareInfo = textA.CompareInfo;
    var aCompareInfo = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo(lcid ?? textA.LCID).CompareInfo;
    //var compareOptions = ConvertCompareOptions(textA.SqlCompareOptions);
    var compareOptions = GetCompareOptions(caseInsensitive, accentInsensitive, kanaInsensitive, widthInsensitive);

    // ...  more code ...

    // first comparison
    if (aCompareInfo.Compare(textA.Value, 0, aLength, textB.Value, 0, bLength, compareOptions) == 0) { return 0; }

    // ...  more code ...

    var cost = (aCompareInfo.Compare(textA.Value, i, 1, textB.Value, j, 1, compareOptions) == 0) ? 0 : 1;

    // ...  more code ...
}

private static CompareOptions GetCompareOptions(bool? caseInsensitive, bool? accentInsensitive, bool? kanaInsensitive, bool? widthInsensitive)
{
    var compareOptions = CompareOptions.None;

    compareOptions |= (caseInsensitive ?? false) ? CompareOptions.IgnoreCase : CompareOptions.None;
    compareOptions |= (accentInsensitive ?? false) ? CompareOptions.IgnoreNonSpace : CompareOptions.None;
    compareOptions |= (kanaInsensitive ?? false) ? CompareOptions.IgnoreKanaType : CompareOptions.None;
    compareOptions |= (widthInsensitive ?? false) ? CompareOptions.IgnoreWidth : CompareOptions.None;

    return compareOptions;
}
```

After updating my assembly and UDF declarations, I can call the function like so:

```sql
print dbo.LevenshteinDistance('abc', 'ABC', null, 1, 1, 1, 1)
print dbo.LevenshteinDistance('abc', 'ABC', null, 0, 0, 0, 0)
```

And now the first call returns 0 (database default culture, everything Insensitive) while the second call returns 3 (database default culture, everything Sensitive).

Comment: Hey there. It's been a few years, but as I look at this again I just noticed a potential issue: there's no way to indicate a binary collation (either `*_BIN` or `*_BIN2`). Of course, needing to emulate a binary collation might be an infrequent use-case and so perhaps impractical. But, if needed, you could probably indicate "binary" by passing in the LCID as a negative value and use the sign as the flag. However, that invalidates the `NULL` scenario that takes the LCID of the DB's default collation. OR, since you are using `bool?`, you could interpret all 4 set to `NULL` as being binary.

Comment: Also, just FYI: you technically didn't / don't need to use `int?` and  `bool?` as the parameter types since the `SqlInt32` and `SqlBoolean` types, respectively, already encapsulate that behavior (all of the `Sql*` types do, actually). In fact, `SqlBoolean` even has properties for `IsTrue` (`true` if set to true, else false, even if `NULL`), and `IsFalse` (`true` if set to false, else false, even if `NULL`).

Comment: It has been too many years! I remember writing this code, but for some reason we never put it into production. Instead, I had to rewrite it as a couple T-SQL User Defined Functions. 
Despite the performance hit, at least they work and no one is offended at installing custom DLLs on the SQL Server.

Answer (score 2):

> How can I get a SQL String's collation within a CLR function?

Unfortunately you cannot. According to the TechNet page for [Collation and CLR Integration Data Types](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131091.aspx), in the "Parameter Collation" section:

> When you create a common language runtime (CLR) routine, and a parameter of a CLR method bound to the routine is of type **SqlString**, SQL Server creates an instance of the parameter with the default collation of the database containing the calling routine. If a parameter is not a **SqlType** (for example, **String** rather than **SqlString**), the collation information from the database is not associated with the parameter.

So, the behavior that you witnessed regarding the `CompareInfo` and `SqlCompareOptions` properties of the `textA` input param is, while unfortunate / frustrating / incomprehensible, at least inline with how the documentation says that the system should be working.

Hence, your solution of passing the properties in via separate input params is the way to go (although you *really* should be using the SqlTypes of `SqlInt32` and `SqlBoolean` ;-).

Answer (score 2):

There is another way that some may consider better  if your solution doesn't involve strings greater than 4K.  Make your data-type 'object' rather than SqlString.  This is equivalent to SQL_VARIANT.  Although variants incur a bit more overhead than standard types they can hold strings with arbitrary collation.

```
SELECT dbo.ClrCollationTest(N'Anything' collate latin1_general_cs_as),
       dbo.ClrCollationTest(N'Anything' collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS);
```

The above returns 0 and 1 respectively when the CLR is coded thus:

```
public static SqlBoolean ClrCollationTest(object anything)
{
    if (anything is SqlString)
        return new SqlBoolean(((SqlString)anything).SqlCompareOptions.HasFlag(SqlCompareOptions.IgnoreCase));
    else throw new ArgumentException(anything.GetType().Name + " is not a valid parameter data type.  SqlString is required.");
}
```

Comment: This is a misleading answer. Collation encompasses more than the "compare options": it also includes which dictionary / code page / sorting and equivalence-rules. If you can't capture `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1` vs  `latin1_general` vs ?? then you don't really have the collation. Also, it needs to be noted that using `SQL_VARIANT` / `object` has the following two drawbacks: **1)** it is slow, and **2)** it cannot hold any blob type, such as `NVARCHAR(MAX)`, hence you are limited to `NVARCHAR(4000)`.

Comment: Perhaps question's title is what turned out to be misleading. I suggested a way to get everything the OP needed without the need for ANY params only after the OP posted an apparently sufficient 'solution' that involved only compareOptions values.  
My doubt that Levenshtein Distance would ever be used on strings longer than 400 much less 4000 bytes made this suggestion seem reasonably useful rather than misleading.

Comment: Good points. And I did some further testing and found that the LCID does come through correctly when using `object`, which allows for getting the full COLLATE setting when combined with the `SqlCompareOptions`. So this does seem to answer the question. If you add those 2 notes (max size and performance hit) then I will upvote. I understand that this specific case should not need a MAX type, but people reading this should know of those two drawbacks before trying to apply this everywhere they can ;-).

Comment: Well, _someone_ (i.e. "Community") made those 2 updates so I upvoted.

Comment: It was me, I just wasn't logged in.