# SQL Server: How can we call the same UDF with different collations

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, user-defined-functions, collation

I'm writing a User Defined Function (UDF) in SQL Server 2008 R2.  I'd like to have the UDF use different collations on different calls.  Is this possible?  Is it possible to dynamically change a collation based upon user input?

From Intellisense, what little I can find online, it seems that collation must be specified in the actual T-SQL code and cannot be applied as a variable or input parameter.  Are there ways around this, specifically ways that can work inside a UDF?

**EDIT**: As requested, here is the UDF I'm working with.  My intent is to call it both with and without "xxxx sensitive" settings for sorting a query's results by "relevance".

```sql
/*
    T-SQL Implementation of Levenshtein Edit Distance.
*/
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[LevenshteinDistanceSQL] (
    @textA varchar(max)
    , @textB varchar(max)
)
RETURNS INT
AS
Begin

    DECLARE
        @aLength int
        , @bLength int
        , @prevSize int
        , @currentSize int
        , @previousDistances varbinary(max)
        , @currentDistances varbinary(max)
        , @result int

    SET @aLength = LEN(@textA)
    SET @bLength = LEN(@textB)
    SET @result = NULL

    -- Degenerate Cases

    -- want calling routine to specify the collation of this comparison
    If (@textA = @textB) SET @result = 0;

    If (@aLength = 0) SET @result = @bLength;
    If (@bLength = 0) SET @result = @aLength;

    If (@result IS NULL)
    Begin
        -- Set sizes of tables to length of largest input text, plus 1
        SET @prevSize = CASE WHEN @aLength > @bLength THEN @aLength ELSE @bLength END + 1;
        SET @currentSize = CASE WHEN @aLength > @bLength THEN @aLength ELSE @bLength END + 1;

        -- Initialize Previous distances
        DECLARE
            @i int
            , @j int
            , @cost int
            , @curDistLastCost int
            , @prevDistCurCost int
            , @prevDistLastCost int
            , @charA char(1)
            , @charB char(1)

        SET @i = 0
        SET @previousDistances = 0x -- empty varbinary
        While (@i < @prevSize)
        Begin
            SET @previousDistances = @previousDistances + CONVERT(binary(4), @i)
            SET @i = @i + 1;
        End

        -- Process @textA
        SET @i = 0
        While (@i < @aLength)
        Begin
            SET @currentDistances = CONVERT(binary(4), @i + 1);

            -- Process @textB
            SET @j = 0
            While (@j < @bLength)
            Begin
                SET @charA = SUBSTRING(@textA, @i + 1, 1)
                SET @charB = SUBSTRING(@textB, @j + 1, 1)

               -- want calling routine to specify the collation of this comparison
                SET @cost = CASE WHEN @charA = @charB THEN 0 ELSE 1 END;

                SET @curDistLastCost = CONVERT(int, SUBSTRING(@currentDistances, @j * 4 + 1, 4))
                SET @prevDistCurCost = CONVERT(int, SUBSTRING(@previousDistances, (@j + 1) * 4 + 1, 4))
                SET @prevDistLastCost = CONVERT(int, SUBSTRING(@previousDistances, @j * 4 + 1, 4))

                SET @currentDistances = @currentDistances + CONVERT(binary(4), CASE
                    WHEN @curDistLastCost < @prevDistCurCost AND @curDistLastCost < @prevDistLastCost THEN @curDistLastCost + 1
                    WHEN @prevDistCurCost < @curDistLastCost AND @prevDistCurCost < @prevDistLastCost THEN @prevDistCurCost + 1
                    ELSE @prevDistLastCost + @cost
                    END)

                SET @j = @j + 1
            End

            -- copy current distances to previous distances for next iteration
            SET @previousDistances = @currentDistances

            SET @i = @i + 1;
        End

        SET @result = CONVERT(int, SUBSTRING(@currentDistances, @bLength * 4 + 1, 4))
    End

    RETURN @result
End
```

Called like this:

```sql
declare @text varchar(50)

set @text = 'c'

select
    *
from
    Skills as s
where
    s.Name like '%' + @text + '%'
order by
    dbo.LevenshteinDistance(@text, s.Name) -- COLLATE Latin1_General_100_CI_AI
    , dbo.LevenshteinDistance(@text, s.Name) -- COLLATE Latin1_General_100_CS_AS_KS_WS
    , s.Name
```

Being able to specify the collation will allow me to sort the shortest edit-distance (insensitive) to the top of the results; and within an insensitive edit distance the case, accent, etc. matches will be at the top.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish by a) using a UDF and b) passing in a COLLATION? UDF's cannot use dynamic SQL. Is this a situation where a stored proc might work?

Comment: Stored Proc won't work in this case as I need to call the function twice in the ORDER BY clause of my query.  Each call using a different collation.  For the time being, I could write two UDF's, hard-coding the collation in each; but if we need more collations in the future (like when we support languages beyond English) we'll need a more general solution.

Comment: Ok regarding UDF vs proc. So the COLLATION needs to happen inside the UDF and not on the returned value of the UDF?

Comment: Correct - I need to use the specified collation for string comparisons within the UDF.

Comment: I think the usual approach would be to use different functions and to modify the query to use the different functions as needed.  Do you know what collations you need?  Could you use an `IF ... THEN` block in the function with different queries?  Can you wrap the query that would be calling this function in a stored procedure?

Comment: @BaconBits I may have to take your advice.  It is more specific than I'd like - hard-coding the collations, but it would work.  However, I've been informed that we are looking to support additional languages in our project, once that happens hard-coding will quickly become impractical (SQL Server 2008 R2 has close to 3000 collations).

Comment: There might be a way to do this. Any chance on getting at least a generic form of your UDF posted so I can test a scenario that is as close to yours as possible?

Comment: Overall, this strikes me as a problem that *would have been solved already* if it were necessary, instead of being basically functionally impossible.  Considering the impact collation has on indexing and the like, I'm really struggling to find a good reason to need to define this at the function level.  If users need different collations, it makes more sense to set the database or columns to the collation the users actually need.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to accomplish this, and both require SQLCLR. As you have seen, T-SQL does not allow for specifying the COLLATION dynamically, but in .Net you can :). And in fact, there are two additional benefits to using SQLCLR for this purpose:

1. You can get more granular control over the options of doing the comparison. Look at the [CompareOptions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.compareoptions.aspx) enum. For example, it has an option for `IgnoreSymbols`:

   > Indicates that the string comparison must ignore symbols, such as white-space characters, punctuation, currency symbols, the percent sign, mathematical symbols, the ampersand, and so on.
2. SQLCLR UDFs can allow for a parallel execution plan, whereas T-SQL UDFs will always disallow parallel plans. In order to allow for a parallel plan, the SQLCLR UDF needs to be deterministic *and* marked as `IsDeterministic=true` as well as not do any data access (no need to mark this explicitly as it is the default).

That said, here are some additional notes:

- All implementations of the Levenshtein Distance algorithm that I have seen assume an Ordinal comparison (i.e. any of the `*_BIN` collations). But I suppose for what you are trying to accomplish it could prove to be interesting :)
- Given what you are trying to accomplish, when taking the SQLCLR approach, you don't actually need to pass in any collation info. The reason is that each particular language (i.e. collation) controls both the comparison options for equality as well as sorting. But sorting is not involved in the Levenshtein Distance algorithm. That reduces the need to just two variations:

  - Fully insensitive (at least for `IgnoreCase` and `IgnoreNonSpace`, and  optionally for `IgnoreKanaType`, `IgnoreSymbols`, and `IgnoreWidth`)
  - Fully sensitive (i.e. `Ordinal`)

So, your two options are:

1. Do this fully in .Net:

   Implement the algorithm fully in C# (or VB.Net) and use the [CompareInfo.Compare (String, String, CompareOptions)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0sk4bdtt.aspx) method. In this scenario you need either two functions, one that is "sensitive" and one that is "insensitive", or a single function for both that takes an input parameter (SqlBoolean, perhaps) for @SensitiveComparison. But the particular language of the strings to be compared is irrelevant so you would technically support all languages on day 1 :).
2. Keep the algorithm in T-SQL. In this scenario you would execute a `SqlCommand` using a connection string of `"Context Connection = true;"`.  Your function would take in a `SqlString` of a collation name and use that to concatenate into the algorithm in the two spots that do a comparison. [I don't see much benefit to this option over the fully C# option, and in fact it *should* be a little slower as .Net code should be faster for this type of thing.]

In either case, it should be noted that this can be accomplished in an assembly marked with `PERMISSION_SET = SAFE`. Meaning, there is **absolutely no security risk** in implementing this functionality (as described here). And, for anyone who is still under the (false) impression that SQLCLR / enabling CLR Integration is inherently a security risk, I wrote an article (part of a series on SQLCLR) that covers this topic of security from various angles and with plenty of examples to test for yourself: [Stairway to SQLCLR Level 3: Security (General and SAFE Assemblies)](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/SQLCLR/109905/) (free registration required).

Comment: I actually implemented a SQLCLR assembly, just like you suggested, before asking this question.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26789247. However, our team lead wanted to avoid deploying custom assemblies to our database servers.  As a result I needed to re-implement in T-SQL, which led to this question.  I ended up implementing two stored procs, one sensitive and the other insensitive.  Performance-wise, the CLR routine is 7-8 times faster than T-SQL.  Even with T-SQL, we still have acceptable response times in our app.

Comment: @Zarepheth Interesting that you had done it correctly and were told to do it incorrectly. String handling is much better (not just faster) in .Net, especially when dealing with non-Latin1 character sets. Why weren't you allowed to do this in the correct, efficient, maintainable, scalable, less-error-prone way? I added a final paragraph to my answer :). I just added an answer (and +1 yours) to your other question. I think it will take more than 2 T-SQL UDFs. `Latin1_General_100_BIN2` will catch most stuff for "fully sensitive", but the rest? I don't think it will work without LOTS of functions.

Comment: I think the idea was to simplify deployment.  Adding CLR assemblies means more projects in the solution, ensuring the server hosting team is okay with it, and making sure our deployment processes include the assemblies when we update the database.  For historical reasons, possibly due to incorrect concerns with security, CLR assemblies have been prohibited or strongly discouraged.  When the only solution is to use them, that's when things will likely change...

Comment: @Zarepheth : well, as far as I can see with this request and wanting to support many / all languages, the code complexity of the T-SQL UDFs will probably be higher than the complexity of figuring out how to get an assembly into your deploy process :). And _that_ is something I have thoughts on as well. I wrote a small console app that turns the DLL into a set of hex chars to be placed in a SQL script. Deployment is very simple. Check out the install script for http://www.sqlsharp.com/ and tell me that isn't easy :).